# uncaught reference trying to debug streamline.js generated javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've set up streamline.js and I have successfully generated some code with it using `_node --standalone -c stest._js`, and this code seems to run okay in the browser.  However, the generated code is not readable and is impossible to debug in something like Chrome's developer tools.  However, it appears that there is a command line option `--source-map` which allows you to "seamlessly debug streamline code thanks to JavaScript source maps."  The [section](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs#debugging-with-source-maps) on this is very brief, suggesting that it is only necessary to include this extra command-line option.

But when I do this, my code will no longer run.  I get a javascript error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

This code is running in a browser, I'm not using any libraries.  I suspect that for some reason the code generated with the `--source-map` option needs some library with a function called "require", but the documentation says nothing about this that I can find.  Since it doesn't seem to require this to *not* have debugging information, I'm a bit at a loss here.  How do I get this code to run?  Can I not run standalone in a browser with debugging info enabled?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Chrome Pretty print]

It's not exactly the answer you are looking for however this button "Pretty Print" on Chrome Dev Tools has helped me sometimes.

It breaks lines in a minified file so stepping through the code is a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to load the following files, in the order below, in the browser *before* the javascript created by `_node --source-map --standalone -c stest._js`

```
streamline/lib/callbacks/require-stub.js
streamline/lib/util/future.js
streamline/lib/callbacks/runtime.js
streamline/lib/callbacks/builtins.js
streamline/lib/callbacks/flows.js
```

These files are on github under https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs/tree/master/lib

As a note, `require-stub.js` doesn't actually load anything, but provides the needed `require` function.